Selenium IDE command "execute script" not working
I'm a beginner with Selenium IDE.  I want to use the "execute script" command. I created a two-line script to try it out but I'm not seeing the results I expect.
In Selenium IDE I created these two commands:
open http://www.duckduckgo.com 
execute script alert("Hello Duck")
I run the test and the browser window (Firefox) opens to the specified URL and then the 'execute script' command turns green to indicate it was performed, but no alert dialog appears.
Am I doing something wrong?
Note that I tried this in Chromium with the Selenium IDE extension and it works fine.

You need to update your tags to reflect your question. You aren't using Selenium WebDriver, you are using Selenium IDE.

default unhandledPromptBehaviour is dismiss and notify methinks.  (notify=throw exception, dismiss = close/cancel prompt)  So that'll happen on your next action.
